# LaTeX pushes the cell off the bottom of the page

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I have a problem with too long text in one cell.

Text in cell is autocreated, and I cannot know previously how long will be it. When text is too long LaTeX pushes the cell off the bottom of the page.

Is the some way to teach LaTeX automatically to transfer text on the next page (not out of page)? Maybe you can offer some package that can fix my problem.

For table creating I use `longtable`.

[image]

Some example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}|}
Text & Steps \\ \hline
  & 1.step \newline
    2.step \newline
    3.step \newline
    4.step \newline
    5.step \newline
    6.step \newline
    7.step \newline
    ................. \newline
    57.step \newline
    58.step \newline
    59.step \newline
    60.step \newline
    61.step \newline
    62.step \newline
    63.step \newline
    64.step \newline
    65.step \newline
    66.step \newline
    67.step \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

One more example:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{3.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{\normalsize{Description:}}}     & \multicolumn{3}{p{7.5cm}|} {Some description of Table} \\ \hline
\textit{\textbf{\normalsize{Steps:}}} & \multicolumn{3}{p{7.5cm}|} {
1. step  \newline
2. step  \newline
3. step  \newline
4. step  \newline
5. step  \newline
6. step  \newline
7. step  \newline
......   \newline
63. step \newline
64. step \newline
65. step \newline
66. step \newline
67. step 
} \\  \hline
\textit{\textbf{\normalsize{Remarks:}}}         & \multicolumn{3}{p{7.5cm}|} {---} \\                     \hline
\textit{\textbf{\normalsize{Date:}}}     & \multicolumn{3}{p{7.5cm}|} {2012/10/23} \\                     \hline
\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\textit{\textbf{\normalsize{Approval}}}}   & \normalsize{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{+}} & \normalsize{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{+}} & \normalsize{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\textbf{-}}} \\   \hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image: one more example]

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Did you re-run this? Sometime `longtable` requires several runs.  As @hpesoj626 suggested it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates the problem.   Otherwise it is difficult to know what went wrong.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.  To mark a large block of inline code, select it and press `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 3):

Cells of tables are not breakable across pages. Perhaps you can teach the autocreation process to make single cells instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}|}
Text & Steps \\ \hline
  & 1.step \tabularnewline
  & 2.step \tabularnewline
  & 3.step \tabularnewline
  & 4.step \tabularnewline
  & 5.step \tabularnewline
  & 6.step \tabularnewline
  & 7.step \tabularnewline
  & ................. \tabularnewline
  & 57.step \tabularnewline
  & 58.step \tabularnewline
  & 59.step \tabularnewline
  & 60.step \tabularnewline
  & 61.step \tabularnewline
  & 62.step \tabularnewline
  & 63.step \tabularnewline
  & 64.step \tabularnewline
  & 65.step \tabularnewline
  & 66.step \tabularnewline
  & 67.step \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]